# Does a Vietnamese citizen need a transit visa for South Korea?

Tags: south-korea, transit-visas, vietnamese-citizens

I am a Vietnamese passport holder. I'm going back to Viet Nam from Montreal this December, and I will transit at Incheon Airport for a few hours. Do I need a Korean visa just for transiting, either from Montreal to Hanoi or from Hanoi back to Montreal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No if you remain at the airport, have at least 6 months of validity on passport and have proofs on onward flight. Source: http://www.vinavisas.com/south%20korea-visa/vnm-vietnamese-passport/transit

Answer (score 4):

You may not require a visa since Korea has an exception for holders of a Canadian visa.

Also, if you will remain airside, and any baggage is checked through to your final destination, then no visa will be required.

> Korea (Rep.) (KR)
>
> Visa Exemptions:
>
> - Holders of a visa issued by Australia, Canada, Japan, New   Zealand or USA to nationals of any country except for Cuba,

Source: https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client_post.cgi